# How I can have different controls in different tabs and one Fragment using TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I am trying to understand how tabs are working but I am confused. I created a sample app with Android Studio wizard where there is one fragment.

How I can have in this one fragment but in different tabs different elements I only need to do something in onCreateView or in FragmentPagerAdapter?

The part of the adapter is:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "CONTACTS";
            case 1:
                return "DETAILS";
            case 2:
                return "GENERAL";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your page adapter send different arguments to the fragment and on the onCreateView() of your fragment load the view according to the arguments received.

Comment: any example available?

Comment: getting a new instance from a Fragment class using a constructor is discouraged. Use a bundle to send arguments.

Answer (score 0):

An example on how to achieve the task.

```
//sending different arguments from the view pager adapter
public Fragment getItem(int position){
      Fragment fragment=new PlaceHolderFragment();
      //a bundle is used to wrap the data you send to the fragment
      Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
      //change whats inside the bundle based on your page
      switch(position){
          case 0:{
              bundle.putInt("dataForThisPosition",12);
              break;
          }case 1:{
              bundle.putInt("dataForThisPosition",13);
              break;
          }
          //this can continue
      }
      //attach the bundle to the fragment
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);
      return fragment;
}

//then in your fragment class
//receiving the data sent from pager adapter
public View onCreateView(/*parameters*/){
    Bundle receivedBundle=getArguments();
    int datForThisPosition=recievedBundle.getInt("dataForThisPosition",12/*default value*/);
    //create your view based on the info received.
}
```